# Upgrade JDK on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, java, java-6

I am using default JDK on my MacBook Pro which runs with 10.6.8. I want to upgrade my JDK version but I didn't find on Oracle web site. Where can I download for Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Java JDK 7 comes from Oracle and requires OSX 10.7.3 or higher See [Oracle's mac install info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/index.html#mac)

Earlier OS and JDKs were released by Apple. Latest version is [1.6.0_37](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1573)